# Javascript changing the visibility of a div depending on what option in <select> not working

Tags: javascript, function, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to create a function where the user picks an option from a  drop-down box, and the site should show a hidden div depending on which option the user picks.

The Dropdown box:

```
<select id="pick">
            <option value="v2">2</option>
            <option value="v3">3</option>
</select>
```

Button:

```
<input type="button" value="Generate" onclick="genFunc(this)" />
```

JavaScript-function:

```
function genFunc(sel) {
    var value = sel.value;
    var divChange = value;
    var divChange = "document.getElementById("+ sel.value +")";

    divChange.style.visibility= "visible" ;

        }
```

CSS:

```
#v2 {
    visibility: hidden;
}

#v3 {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

HTML-divs:

```
<div id="v2">test1</div>
<div id="v3">test2</div>
```

When I press the button I get this error instead:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'visibility' of undefined

I can't find out why I'm getting this error.
Also, I'm sorry if all of this is written clumpsy.

Comment: Why have you wrapped the DOM getter within quotes? A string doesn't have `style` property. You can use variables to represent their value in an expression as they are, no need to mess around with quotes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two problems

1. `this` value you are passing in `onclick` is `button`, not `select`
2. You are using string, to get `divChange`, instead of an actual function

Try this:

```
function genFunc() {
    var sel = document.getElementById("pick");
    var divChange = document.getElementById(sel.value);
    divChange.style.visibility= "visible" ;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I got a little lost in a jungle of different solutions offered by google. This made it work as I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to call function with this object on button click

**Html for Button**

```
<input type="button" value="Generate" onclick="genFunc()" />
```

**Js Code**

```
function genFunc() {    
  var e = document.getElementById("pick");
  var value = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
  var divChange = document.getElementById(value);
  divChange.style.visibility= "visible" ;
}
```

Working [Example](https://jsfiddle.net/fNPvf/30818/)

Answer (score 0):

you are using the wrong element values,have to pick the value of select option. Check this fiddle...
https://jsfiddle.net/pLsdspon/1/

```
<select id="pick">
        <option value="v2">2</option>
        <option value="v3">3</option>
</select>
<input type="button" value="Generate" onclick="genFunc(this)" />
<div id="v2">test1</div>
<div id="v3">test2</div>
<script>function genFunc(sel) {
var e = document.getElementById("pick");
var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
var divChange = document.getElementById(strUser);
divChange.style.visibility= "visible" ;
        }</script><style>#v2 {
    visibility: hidden;
}

#v3 {
    visibility: hidden;
}</style>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
$("#pick").change(function(){
      if(parseInt($(this).text()) == 2){
        $("#v2").show();
        $("#v2").hide();
      }else{
        $("#v2").hide();
        $("#v2").show();
      }

});
```